# Simplifying $(p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (p ∧ q) ∨ r$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I'm trying to solve exercise from Thomas Koshy "Discrete Mathematics and it's Applications" where I need to simplify next expression:

$(p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (p ∧ q) ∨ r$

I tried to use Distributive laws in almost any variation of it but end up with a mess and only make expression more complex.
Maybe someone can help me find the right way to simplify it correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the distributive law, the proposed expression is equivalent to:
\begin{align*}
(p\wedge\neg q)\vee(p\wedge q)\vee r & \Longleftrightarrow (p\wedge(\neg q\vee q))\vee r\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (p\wedge t)\vee r\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow p\vee r
\end{align*}
where $t$ denotes a tautology.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Could you please specify how can we get $(p∧(¬q∨q))$?

Because using double distribution I'm getting:
$(p∧¬q)∨(p∧q) ⟺ (p∨p)∧(p∨q)∧(¬q∨p)∧(¬q∨q)$

Then I can remove $(¬q∨q)$ as tautology, and reduce $(p∨p)⟺p$

Which left me:
$p∧(p∨q)∧(¬q∨p)$

Comment: I have applied the relation
$$p\wedge(q\vee r) \Longleftrightarrow (p\wedge q)\vee(p\wedge r)$$

Comment: Ah, that's the game changer. I tried to apply distribution directly to relations I have and haven't even thought about use it backwards. That makes sense now, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome @harmoxyne ! I am glad to help.